# Where to download System.Data.Objects.DLL for EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I sincerely ask for your advice, how do I download these two files?

- System.Data.Objects.dll
- System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.dll

Comment: Typically, you don't.  The usual approach is to use NuGet in your development environment, and use WebDeploy when you push to your server.

Comment: I've tried,But I couldn't find anything about it

Answer (score 2):

They come with the .Net Framework. Do yourself a favour and download and install Visual Studio the community version.

Or use VSCode and install the .Net Framework: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework